# how to work with Eclipse Source Code in Eclipse itself

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

I have download entire Eclipse Helios/Indigo version Source Code. Now I want to work on it like some modifications and all. So I imported the entire sourceCode but now I am getting n number of errors while compiling. Moreover I am trying to RunAs> Plug-in is confusing me about the output I am getting is the changed one or what.

My Problems are-
How to import entire Eclipse SOurceCode in eclipse?
How to build the Eclipse SourceCode properly?
After modification in the SC of Eclipse , how to check the changes feasility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would define a target definition for your Eclipse distribution. Include all the features (including source) in the definition. Then you can use you importer to import plugins from your target definition into your workspace with sources and work from that. Having target definition is easier because you can change your setup on-demand.

Edit: Forgot to mention that in import wizard (File -> Import -> Plug-in Development -> Plug-ins and Fragments) make sure you select "Project with source folders" under "Import as". Otherwise class files will be imported as jars and not deflated into your project. Just makes it easier to work with them this way.

[image]

Comment: Can you please state me any example for the same. And will the target defination setup will remove the issues of dependencies as it oftienly comes

Comment: There are plenty tutorials on the web, e.g., www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html#targetplatform_control or

Comment: www.modumind.com/2009/09/01/creating-an-eclipse-rcp-target-platform/ (darn phone, haha). In short: create a new Target Definition, add to it the Indigo Software Site, include features and their sources, and "Set as Target Platform".

Comment: link that s.d. provided (http://www.modumind.com/2009/09/01/creating-an-eclipse-rcp-target-platform/) explains it perfectly.

Just to add, clicking on "Content" tab will show all plugins that make particular feature that you selected and you can use filter to find a particular plugin and see what version and source is part of that feature.